# Upgrade Magento 2.3 and store code base is not found

Tags: magento2, database, upgrade, websites

I upgraded my Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.6, I'm seeing this message in the frontend.

```
The website with code base that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again.
```

[image: The website with code base that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again.]

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by changing in my database the store code to **base** in the `store_website` table.

[image: Magento 2 store website]